# Combres 2, 404 error

Tags: c#, combres

Am trying to get combres working with my .net 4 web form on IIS 7.

Everything is working locally, however when made the site live the following path comes up with 404 error

```
www.mydomain.co.uk/combres.axd/siteCss/-1938526509/
```

But if i remove the / at the end it works.

```
www.mydomain.co.uk/combres.axd/siteCss/-1938526509
```

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Found the reason was not working. UrlScan 3.1 was the problem. Any one know how to get around this, apart from removing urlscan?

Answer (score 2):

In your combres.xml file you probably have defaultDebugEnabled set to false. This leads it to work on local but generates urls like these on live. Set it to auto and it should work.

```
<resourceSets url="~/combres.axd" defaultDuration="300"
                                defaultVersion="auto"
                                defaultDebugEnabled="auto"
                                defaultIgnorePipelineWhenDebug="true"
                                localChangeMonitorInterval="30"
                                remoteChangeMonitorInterval="60">
```